# Does removing a token from play trigger effects that happen when a dude is discarded or aced?

Tags: doomtown-reloaded

Say that I have a [Gunslinger](http://dtdb.co/en/card/01146) token in a shootout and he gets discarded or Aced. Per the card's text, you need to "Remove this token from the game after this shootout."

I presume that this means they go neither to the discard pile, nor to Boot Hill after a shootout. Does that mean that effects that trigger when a dude is discarded or aced happen to the Gunslinger? For instance, the [Undertaker](http://dtdb.co/en/card/01076) deed has an effect that happens whenever a dude is aced. If the Gunslinger is aced in a shootout, does the Undertaker effect still happen even though the Gunslinger doesn't go to Boot Hill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assign 2 casualties to a dude (token dudes are still dudes!) they're considered aced unless they're Harrowed in which case it'd take 3 casualties!  Per the FAQ:

> When a Token Dude is aced or discarded it is removed from play instead of going to the discard pile or boot hill.
>   It will still trigger events like collecting a bounty or the Undertaker giving its controller 2 ghost rock.

Comment: Can you include a link to the FAQ?